# how do I start my hyperledger fabirc project without the fabric-sample?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am new to hyperledger fabric and have tried to run the farbic-sample. I am going to build my own dapp, but I cannot see how to start my project without the fabric-sample, because all the tutorials I found did not tell me how. How can I get those folders and stuffs for my own project? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the fabric samples you can find first_network folder which contains byfn.sh which includes commands how to generate crypto materials and how to up network with binaries, what i meant is you can build your own network with your own customization and just use those commands to up your customized network.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set your own fabric running environment?

[Single Org configuration in Composer](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org)

Above link is from composer to set up a single organisation, but it contains how to configure fabric as well. Every single project will have its own name, number of organisations, id credentials etc. I am not sure whether you will use composer or not. But in any case, you need to know how to configure fabric environment for your own project.

You need to understand how to setup fabric for single organisation in the beginning.
After then you can do more about multiple-organisation project.

You should understand every single line of byfn.sh to configure your own fabric.
I would recommend starting from basic setup fabic and composer first to understand system. Or you can try to find good fabric example from github.